# what layer does SSL handshake happen?

Tags: ssl

I have a very simple question.
I've been reading about the process of SSL handshake.

Which layer does SSL handshake happen?

Is it happening at the Application Layer?

Does this mean that each communication in the SSL handshake is subject to the normal TCP/IP SYN, SYN-ACK,ACK,GET,FIN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL handshake happens on the TCP layer, which means that:

1. First the TCP connection is established in the usual way
2. SSL handshake is performed through that established connection.

SSL handshake is just exchanging binary messages between two TCP-connected endpoints.
Exactly the same applies to sending/receiving data beteween those endpoints: the user data is wrapped in SSL binary messages as their payload. This enables various other features (e.g. transparent user data compression - which is enabled by default AFAIK).

Hope that helps.